# Aerospike multiple filter query?

Tags: filter, udf, aerospike

Reading the documentation did not help me much.

1)As I understood, there is no ability to use multiple filters at one query. If so, how with Aerospike java client API, I write such as query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN1 = 1 AND COLUMN2 = 2
```

2) If there is no possibility to use JAVA CLIENT API for that purpose, must I write own UDF for filtering the data?

3) If I write own UDF (that filteres data),  would it be fast or should I use secondary-index in order to make it's execution faster?

Answer (score 3):

[Predicate filtering](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html) was added in [release 3.12](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-aerospike-3-12/) on March 15. You can use the [PredExp](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html) class of the Java client to build complex filters such as the one you mentioned. It also currently exists for the [C](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/d9/d10/as__predexp_8h_source.html), [C#](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/csharp/html/T_Aerospike_Client_PredExp.htm) and [Go](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/predexp.go) clients.

Predicate filtering can be used to build as complex of a filtering logic as you need, and its executed natively, not through a UDF. You *can* apply a record UDF to any record matched by your filter, if you need to. If you're just trying to get all the records that fit a specific complex predicate criteria don't use a UDF, just the predicate filter itself.

A predicate filter can run faster on top of a secondary index, but that's not required. Without one it'll run against a scan which returns all the records in a namespace/set, applying the filter to each. If you do have a secondary index, make sure to order the WHERE clause to use it. As currently there is no server-side query optimizer, you should optimize the query manually by considering the order of the predicates.

For example, assume you have a set of users with bins *gender*, *age*, and *name*, with the first two indexed, and are looking for all female users between 35 and 44 whose name starts with 'S'. You want to [set the Filter](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/Statement.html#setFilter(com.aerospike.client.query.Filter)) for the [Statement](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/Statement.html) to use the index which returns the fewest records from a query. In this case, using the index on *age* would return fewer records than *gender*, and execute faster. Within the PredExp you also want to order the predicates to short-circuit and skip a record being matched as soon as possible. In this case you likely want to compare the *gender* bin value before the more expensive string regular expression on *name*.

Comment: PredExp is deprecated now. Expressions have been introduced in 5.2+ versions.
https://docs.aerospike.com/server/guide/expressions

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you cannot get a set of records back directly from an equivalent implementation of the multiple filter query you list. But there is a round about way. You can create SI (secondary-index) on column1 to get the first subset of records, feed that recordset to a stream udf where you can only read records, filter them by column2, return a map of return values. In UDFs, you cannot return a record or set of records or stream subset. However, if you store your record key as a bin in each record, you could return a map of keys and then have access to that subset of records in your application.